# Is there a name for an antipattern where only certain permutations of property values equal a valid object?

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism

I don't know how to describe it in words alone.

It's like suppose we have a hierarchy like

- `IFoo`

  - `Foo1`
  - `Foo2`
- `IBar`

  - `Bar1`
  - `Bar2`
  - `Bar3`

and an object like

```
public class Baz
{
   public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
   public IBar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and business rule like

```
=================================
Foo type | Bar type | Valid Baz?
=================================
| Foo 1  |  Bar 1   |  false   |
---------------------------------
| Foo 1  |  Bar 2   |  false   | 
---------------------------------
| Foo 1  |  Bar 3   |  true    |     
---------------------------------
| Foo 2  |  Bar 1   |  true    | 
---------------------------------
| Foo 2  |  Bar 2   |  true    | 
---------------------------------
| Foo 2  |  Bar 3   |  false   |
```

(Or is this even an anti-pattern?)

Comment: Seems like a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @jaco0646 Not if the abstraction expects equality to differ. For example, [`Collection#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like an anti pattern. You described it on that level of abstraction that I can assume only that `Baz` makes sense only with some implementations of `IFoo` and `IBar` interfaces. In that case, you need to implement extra class which protects system from "bad" `Baz` objects. You can use [Builder](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) or other [Creational Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns) to create only valid `Baz` objects.

With `Builder` it could look like this:

```
Baz validBaz = new BazBuilder().withFoo(foo).withBar(bar).build();
```

You can validate instances in a method or create a set of methods with allowed types:

```
public BazBuilder withBar(Bar1 bar) { ... }
```

and

```
public BazBuilder withBar(Bar2 bar) { ... }
```

So, user can provide only `Bar1` and `Bar2` instances. `Bar3` is not allowed. Of course, in this scenario `Baz` class can not be instantiated in other way.